# "Sort" an Array by Shifting Elements, with constraint

Tags: algorithms

My problem is the following:

> Write an algorithm that takes as input an integer array $A$ and outputs $N$, the **least** nonnegative integer with the following property: $$\exists \text{ an integer array $X$, len($X$) = len($A$) such that }\forall i : |X[i]| \le N \text{ and } X + A \text{ is strictly sorted.}$$

Strictly sorted means $i < j \implies A[i]<A[j]$. Also, $X + A$ denotes component wise addition.

Here are a couple examples

> $A = [3, 2, 1] \implies N = 2\,,\,X=[-2,0,2]$
>
> $A = [5, 2, 5, -1] \implies N = 5\,,\,X=[-5,-1,-3,4]$

At first I thought I could just shift all entries towards the average of the largest inversion (-- to the left of middle ++ to the right), but this was just a heuristic estimate. I have not been able to actually prove anything substantial about $N$.

Not looking for the solution as much as some intuition / a hint.

Comment: From the examples one might guess that $X+A$ will always turn out to be a sequence of consecutive integers. This is not the case as the simple of an already sorted array with large gaps shows (e.g. for  $A=(-10,10,20)$, we can take $N=0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- $X$ is linear in its effect, i.e. you could shift the whole array by some number and it would still work.
- Because of the previous point you could try to search for an array $X'$ of *non-negative* numbers smaller than or equal some $N'$ and then $N = \left\lceil\frac{N'}{2}\right\rceil$.
- Given $N'$, can you check that there exists an array $X'$ such that $A+X'$ is strictly increasing?
- Using the above and binary search you can obtain $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ algorithm.
- Modify the algorithm so that it adjusts/calculates the $N'$ online to obtain $\mathcal{O}(n)$ algorithm.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Ah! So I can initialize $N' = 0$ and step through $A$ using the following iterative scheme: if $A[i] - A[i+1] \le N'$ then update $N'$ with that value plus $1$ and if $A[i+1] < A[i]$, then set $A[i+1] = A[i] + 1$, and continue. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Find an $X$ which satisfies the condition that $X + A$ is strictly sorted with $\max X - \min X$ minimal first (let e.g. $X[0] = 0$ and find the other values accordingly). Then find $k$ such that $X + k$ minimizes $N$, where by $X + k$ I mean the sequence obtained by adding $k$ to all the elements of $X$ (of course $k$ may be negative).